# SpringJUnitConfig configuration class

Tags: spring, spring-test

I got lost when I'm trying to understand @SpringJUnitConfig. I know that @SpringJUnitConfig is a combination of @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) and @ContextConfiguration. However, I don't get in the example that they were showing:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(TestConfig.class) 
class ConfigurationClassJUnitJupiterSpringTests {
    // class body...
}
```

What is this TestConfig.class?

Reference:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/testing/annotations/integration-junit-jupiter.html#integration-testing-annotations-junit-jupiter-springjunitconfig
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/testing/testcontext-framework/ctx-management.html.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found this resource, which basically defines what the classes in the @SpringJUnitConfiguration parameter supposed to be:

> The term “component class” can refer to any of the following:
>
> A class annotated with @Configuration.
>
> A component (that is, a class annotated with @Component, @Service,
> @Repository, or other stereotype annotations).
>
> A JSR-330 compliant class that is annotated with jakarta.inject
> annotations.
>
> Any class that contains @Bean-methods.
>
> Any other class that is intended to be registered as a Spring
> component (i.e., a Spring bean in the ApplicationContext), potentially
> taking advantage of automatic autowiring of a single constructor
> without the use of Spring annotations.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/testing/testcontext-framework/ctx-management/javaconfig.html